# Facing issue in UIScrollview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios8

I am new to ios development.I am working on Swift programming.I am trying to create a scrollview but getting

`"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

every time. I used optional value too in the below code.

Here is my code

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController
    {
     var imagelist=["apple.jpeg","pears.jpeg","banana.jpeg","grapes.jpeg","mango.jpeg"]
     var itemNames = ["Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Grapes", "Mango"]

    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var yPos: Float?
    yPos!=0

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        createScrollview()
    }

    func createScrollview()
    {

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)

        for var index = 0; index < self.imagelist.count; ++index
        {
            var fruitsImgView:UIImageView!
            fruitsImgView.frame=CGRectMake(0,CGFloat(yPos!), 320, 200)
            fruitsImgView.image=UIImage(named: self.imagelist[index])
            scrollView.addSubview(fruitsImgView)
             yPos!=yPos!+200
        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width  * CGFloat(imagelist.count), scrollView.frame.size.height)

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

    }

    }
```

I am unable to get the issue.Please help me if any one worked on it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The second line is an assignment to a nil variable.

```
var yPos: Float?
yPos!=0 // yPos is nil!
```

Replace it with:

```
var yPos = 0 : Float?
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize fruitsImgView. It's an Optional which is always automatically unwrapped to it's contained type. You can't unwrap an Optional in Swift when it contains nil (None).

Initialize fruitsImgView directly before using it:

```
let fruitsImageView = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named: self.imagelist[index]))
```

Note that *UIImageView.init(image:)* doesn't return an optional.

Also you don't need to set the frame on an image view when you initialize it with an image--the frame will be set to the size of the image after initialization.

The same is true for *yPos*, just initialize it to a non-optional:

```
var yPos:Float = 0.0
```